# Hide "Quick Access" pushpin icons in Windows 10 navpane?

Tags: hide, windows-10, pins

So, I'm trying to create a minimal navigation pane in Windows Explorer on Windows 10. Under the Quick Access menu, I have pinned some favorites and frequently accessed folders/shortcuts. I believe that it'd look neater -cleaner-, to not have the little gray push pins icons to the right of the pinned folders and shortcuts. I mean, hello, I pinned them, of course they're pinned, I know it. I guess I was hoping there was some regedit mod I could change right quick to hide all push pins in the navigation pane. Does anyone know of anything like that? Google doesn't seem to....

[Hide Push Pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6oMZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked this several months ago, but here's your answer. It's a bit hack-y and involves 3rd party software, but it works perfectly.

1. Download [Customizer God](http://www.door2windows.com/customizergod/)
2. Create a transparent .png (assuming you have Photoshop/GIMP/Affinity Photo)
3. [Convert the .png to .ico](http://convertico.com/)
4. Open Customizer God. Select "General Icons"
5. Find the Quick Access pin icon by scrolling down a bit.
6. Hit "Change" and select your .ico

The results:

[image]